# Maximising VirtualBox guest machine window size

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside VirtualBox on a MacBook Air 7,2, but the guest screen window size is less than the host display size. I have seen a suggestion that this is possible by installing something called a Guest Additions inside the VB instance from the Devices menu - I tried to this but I get the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and run the following to install VirtualBox Guest Additions:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Additionally, how I increase the maximum size of the guest machine video memory? The maximum is set to 128 MB (in Machine -> Settings -> Display -> Screen), which is way below the 4 GB base memory I specified before created the guest (this is displayed in Machine -> Settings -> System -> Motherboard) - the host machine memory is 8 GB, so that's why I set the guest machine memory to 4 GB.

Comment: Also, I've enabled bidirectionality for the Shared clipboard and drag'n'drop settings (Machine -> Settings -> General -> Advanced), but it doesn't seem to have any effect. My understanding is that this allows selected text in either the guest machine or host machine to be copied between each other seamlessly.  This does not happen at all.

Comment: @ramius You have 8 GB of video memory?! What graphics card do you have? To use the maximum 256 MB video memory, you need to modify the .vbox file with a text editor and change the VRAMSize. If Guest Additions features don't appear to work, make sure you've restarted the instance (preferably using the normal reboot feature).

Comment: Lol, no, not video RAM, I mean just standard RAM.  I think I was confusing the video memory with that - it can't exceed the host graphics card capacity obviously.  Mine is an Intel HD Graphics 6000 card with 1536 MB.